# LINQ grouping and ordering of top 5 rows into ViewModel List

Tags: c#, sql, linq, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a new list of top five hits leaders for my softball web application. I am new to MVC and I am having trouble putting this query together and passing the information to my ViewModel. I would like to use a non-query call like the "var results" in the controller if possible. I am trying to group the AtBats by PlayerID in the Stat table. I would also like to be able to call the FirstName and LastName of the player from the Player table in my view for this list. Thank you for your help!

In Stat.cs

```
using System;

namespace TheFlyingPig.Models
{
    public class Stat
    {
        public int StatID { get; set; }
        public int SeasonID { get; set; }
        public int PlayerID { get; set; }
        public DateTime GameDate { get; set; }
        public int AtBats { get; set; }
        public int Hits { get; set; }
        public int Walks { get; set; }
        public int Singles { get; set; }
        public int Doubles { get; set; }
        public int Triples { get; set; }
        public int HomeRuns { get; set; }
        public int RBIs { get; set; }
        public int Runs { get; set; }
        public int ReachedOnErrors { get; set; }
        public int SacrificeFlies { get; set; }

        public virtual Season Season { get; set; }
        public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In Player.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TheFlyingPig.Models
{
    public class Player
    { 
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Stat> Stats { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In Season.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TheFlyingPig.Models
{
    public class Season
    {
        public int SeasonID { get; set; }
        public string SeasonName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Stat> Stats { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In TeamStat.cs (My ViewModel I am trying to push this data to)

```
//Get the season leaders from controller
public List<Stat> SeasonLeadersHits { get; set; }
```

I have tried both of the following options in my controller (HomeController.cs), but I just can't seem to make any headway here to get the Top 5 Hits leaders for the team.

```
var lastSeasonId = db.Seasons.OrderByDescending(u => u.SeasonID).Select(u => u.SeasonID).FirstOrDefault();

var leadersAtBats = (from s in db.Stats
                     join p in db.Players on s.PlayerID equals p.ID
                     where s.SeasonID == lastSeasonId
                     group s.Hits by s.PlayerID into g
                     order by s.Hits descending
                     select new { LeaderID = g.Key, LeaderList = g.ToList() })
                     .Take(5);

var results = db.Stats.Where(s => s.SeasonID == lastSeasonId).GroupBy(s => s.PlayerID, s => s.Hits, (key, g) => new { PlayerId = key, Hits = g.ToList() });

var view = new TeamStat() { SeasonLeadersHits = results };
return View(view);
```

Comment: Error says it cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TheFlyingPig.Models.Stat>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Your property is `List<Stat> SeasonLeadersHits`, but all your queries are creating anonymous types (the `select` statements), not typeof `Stat`.

Comment: Stephen, I have seen this explanation online, but I do not understand how to fix it. How would I be able to add this into my TeamStat ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>What is the reason for the 'GroupBy'?  It seems to me that all you need to do is select the top 5 rows from db.Stats ordering by Hits descending.  Like this:</strike>

```
var results = (
    from s in db.Stats
    join p in db.Players on s.PlayerID equals p.ID
    where s.SeasonID == lastSeasonId
    order by s.Hits descending
    select new { Player = p, Stats = s })
    .Take(5).ToList();
```

** I'm assuming that each row in `Stats` represents a year.

**Edit:**

Ok, so each Stat object represents a single game (missed that the first time).  If you want the `Stat`s totaled by year, then the piece that is missing from your query is the Sum() of the hits (and probably the other stats as well).  This query will give you the top 5 seasons ranked by total number of hits, along with the season and player associated with it.

```
var hitLeaders = (from s in stats
                  join p in players on s.PlayerID equals p.ID
                  group s by new { s.PlayerID, s.SeasonID } into g
                  select new 
                  { 
                     PlayerID = g.Key.PlayerID, 
                     SeasonID = g.Key.SeasonID, 
                     Hits = g.Sum(sum => sum.Hits),
                     AtBats = g.Sum(sum => sum.AtBats),
                     Walks = g.Sum(sum => sum.Walks),
                     Singles = g.Sum(sum => sum.Singles),
                     Doubles = g.Sum(sum => sum.Doubles),
                     Triples = g.Sum(sum => sum.Triples),
                     HomeRuns = g.Sum(sum => sum.HomeRuns),
                     RBIs = g.Sum(sum => sum.RBIs),
                     Runs = g.Sum(sum => sum.Runs),
                     ReachedOnErrors = g.Sum(sum => sum.ReachedOnErrors),
                     SacrificeFlies = g.Sum(sum => sum.SacrificeFlies)
                  }).OrderByDescending(s => s.Hits).Take(5);
```

Now, the second problem you are going to have is that you can't assign the result of this query to your view model because it produces an `IEnumerable<of AnonymousType>` but the view model is expecting a `List<Stat>`.  What I would suggest is to create an object that represents a total of the stats in a year for a player; something like this:

```
public class TotalStat
{
    public int TotalStatID { get; set; }
    public int SeasonID { get; set; }
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }
    public int AtBats { get; set; }
    public int Hits { get; set; }
    public int Walks { get; set; }
    public int Singles { get; set; }
    public int Doubles { get; set; }
    public int Triples { get; set; }
    public int HomeRuns { get; set; }
    public int RBIs { get; set; }
    public int Runs { get; set; }
    public int ReachedOnErrors { get; set; }
    public int SacrificeFlies { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you'll just need to change the view model to:

```
public List<TotalStat> SeasonLeadersHits { get; set; }
```

And change the query to create an `IEnumerable<TotalStat>`.  You would achieve that by changing `new {}` to `new TotalStat {}`, like so:

```
//...
group s by new { s.PlayerID, s.SeasonID } into g
select new TotalStat
{ 
    PlayerID = g.Key.PlayerID, 
//...
```

Comment: I need the GroupBy because each one player can have multiple StatIDs during the season. I need the total for the season for each player ID and then order by hits descending.

Comment: Works like a charm, but I had to change the public List<TotalStat> SeasonLeadersHits { get; set;} to public IEnumerable<TotalStat> SeasonLeadersHits {get; set; } for it to work. Thank you so much!